# Enabling only one list item in listview

Tags: android

Am doing a simple android application which displays list of videos in list view,my requirement is initially first list item should be enabled and other list items should be disabled,after clicking on that item and viewing the video,when i come back to list view second should be enabled and other should be disabled...the video viewing part am done,can anyone help me in solving the list view problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one item enabled. Keep an index (integer) which one must be enabled in your adapter. In the getView method of your adapter you can use that integer to enable / disable your controls.

If you aren't using a custom adapter, keep the index in your activity/fragment and use the index in onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter *Override* **isEnabled**

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
     boolean result;
     if(position == /*THE POSITION THAT YOU WANT TO ENABLE*/){
        result = true;
     } else{
        result = false;
     }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a ListView with choiceMode set to singleChoice (you can customize the selector with theme) :

```
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```